# Copy all files in directory except ".txt" and not to replace existing files

Tags: shell

i have to copy all the file from source directory to destination directory , but skip all file with extension ".txt" and not to the replace the file if its already present in destination directory

example

source directory

```
    /a/aone.js
    /a/atwo.js
    /b/bone.txt
    /b/btwo.js
```

destination directory

```
    /a/atwo.js
```

then it should only copy

```
    /a/aone.js
    /b/btwo.js
```

and skip "/a/atwo.js" because its already present in destination folder 
and skip "/b/bone.txt" because its extension is ".txt"

i tried this command but this does not work

```
 find /path/to/source/ \( ! -name "*.txt" \) -type f | cp -n /path/to/destination/ -R

 cp -n /path/to/source/*(!*.txt) /path/to/destination/ -R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use `rsync`, (`vaz` is verbose, archive and compress - I believe the other options are self explanatory)

```
rsync -vaz --exclude "*.txt" /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make it difficult. You were on the right track. A simple:

```
cp -an /path/to/source/*.[^t*] /path/to/destination
```

will copy all files from source, except those whose extension begins with a `t` to destination. It will do so without overwriting existing files in destination. This presumes that files do not have more than one dot. If so, then a few more lines of code will be needed.

The following will illustrate use of the above:

```
$ md tmp
$ md a
$ md b
$ touch a/a.{j,k,l,txt}

$ ls -1 a
a.j
a.k
a.l
a.txt

$ cp -an a/a*.[^t*] b

$ ls -1 b
a.j
a.k
a.l
```

using cp, you must match the proper directory depth. If you have another intervening directory, then simply add an additional wildcard. For example:

```
$ ls -1 dat/*/*.[^t*]
dat/a/a.j
dat/a/a.k
dat/a/a.l
dat/b/a.j
dat/b/a.k
dat/b/a.l
```

If your directory structure gets more complex, then go with `find` or `rsync`. Both are excellent tools and `rsync` can handle both local and network transfers. cp is the right tool for small jobs, but when more flexibility is needed, then grab a bigger hammer.

Comment: cp: cannot stat `/path/to/source/*.[^t] :: No such file or directory, 

where as the path is right i cross check it two to three times

Comment: Oops, forgot the `[^t*]`

Comment: There is a simple explanation then. Add another *, `/path/to/source/*/*.[^t*]`